# Create an Image which follows a gaussian distribution using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm am trying to create an 20X20 image using opencv which follows a normal distribution , I understand that there is a randn function which allows me to do something like that , but how should i go about doing it, if I intend to embed a string within the data of the image I'm trying to create ?

Comment: Are you trying to generate gaussian noise in the image or a gaussian shaped filter kernel?

Comment: So you want to create an Image that looks like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Image_gaussian_noise_example.png? And when you talk about embedding a string, do you mean Metadata or Steganography?

Comment: I meant using Steganography and I am trying to create an image that's shown in the link. 
Sorry for not being clearer in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out here for uniform to Gaussian random numbers: http://www.design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/Gaussian.html

If you want to use the last 2 data bits (the least significant ones) for your hidden text, you want to set them to zero in the noised image.

Next, create 3 images:

```
Image noise, mask, textimg

AddNoiseTo(noise) // any kind of noise you want


SetEveryPixel(mask,unsigned char, 255-3)
CvAnd(noise,mask,noise) // to remove noise from the last 2 bits


cvPutText(textimg,yourtext,white);
CvNot(mask,mask) // invert the mask to remove data from the first 6 bits
CvAnd(textimg,mask,textimg) // filter the text image so only last 2 bits are kept
CvOr(noise,textimg,outputimg) // this will merge the two images
```

If you want 7 data bits (to be easier to see the text with the naked eye) subtract 127 (binary for 7 1's) from the mask instead of 3 (11 in binary).